# How can I write the html body of e-mails from asp properly?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am generating html email body from asp but the resulting html code has little changes in each email client (gmail, webmail, outlook). In each of them the email looks different and the code has different changes. For example, I do  tags with a loop a like this:

```
subtotal=0
while not Rs.EOF
subtotal= subtotal + (rs.Fields("Cantidad_LINFACTURA") * rs.Fields("PrecioUnitario_LINFACTURA"))

mensaje= mensaje + "<tr><td align='right'>" + CStr(rs.Fields("Cantidad_LINFACTURA"))+ "</td><td>" + rs.Fields("Descripcion_LINFACTURA") + "</td><td align='right' width='100'>" + CStr(formatNumber(rs.Fields("PrecioUnitario_LINFACTURA"),2)) + " &#8364;</td><td align='right' width='100'>" + CStr(formatNumber(rs.Fields("Cantidad_LINFACTURA") * rs.Fields("PrecioUnitario_LINFACTURA"),2) + " &#8364;</td><td></td></tr>"
rs.moveNext
wend
```

This is without style but sometimes (maybe because of the data) in one of cells and only one it appears without `align="right"` attribute in some email servers.
Sorry for the explanation but I am really frustrated I I don't know why it happens. My temporary solution is not to use styles, but `align=right` attribute fails too.

The third one appears without style but I write all  with an asp loop, at the same way. How is this possible?

Comment: maybe the source could help...

Comment: at the first thanks. It´s too much large to write here, but the the problem is that i write the message with response.write and it looks good but then when I send the email in the different web servers appears those errors

Comment: do you mean    mail.isHTML = True ?

Comment: No... How do you set the body?

Comment: Can you post at least an excerpt of the generating code?

Comment: <td>" + rs.Fields("Descripcion_LINFACTURA") actually IS without style